# Remove duplicate values from a Key using Config::Genral

Tags: perl

Using Config::General Perl module script is loading data from a config file. But if there is duplicate entry in file , i am getting a hash key with array in value , but i want only key and value pair. Want to remove the duplicate values.

```
my $conf_data = new Config::General(-ConfigFile       => $hash{config_file},
                                    -InterPolateEnv   => 1,
                                    -UseApacheInclude => 1,
                                    -IncludeRelative  => 1,
                                  );

  my %conf_data   = $conf_data->getall;
```

Below is the structure of hash i am getting : 
**File Entry**

```
key = AMC
key = AMC
key1 = TEST1
key2 = TEST2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'key' => [
            'AMC',
            'AMC'
          ],
'key1' => 'TEST1',
'key2' => 'TEST2',
```

But i want to get this sctruture:

```
'key' => 'AMC',
'key1' => 'TEST1',
'key2' => 'TEST2',
```

Comment: What if there is more than one value behind the `key` key? Should the last one win?

Comment: Actually the problem is if my mistake there are 2 similar kind of entries added in the file i want to handle that condition .In a hash if the keys are same it overites with the new key . But here in Config::Genral module i am looking for that option how we can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Doing it with Config::General

To do this with Config::General directly, you want [the `-MergeDuplicateOptions` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General#-MergeDuplicateOptions).

> If set to a true value, then duplicate options will be merged. That means, if the same option occurs more than once, the last one will be used in the resulting config hash.

### Doing it manually

If all you want is to replace the array with the last value of the array, you just need to iterate and replace.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %conf_data = (
    'key'  => [ 'AMC', 'AMC' ],
    'key1' => 'TEST1',
    'key2' => 'TEST2',
);

foreach my $key (keys %conf_data) {
    if ( ref $conf_data{$key} && ref $conf_data{$key} eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        $conf_data{$key} = $conf_data{$key}->[-1];
    }
}

use Data::Printer;
p %conf_data;
```

Output:

```
{
    key    "AMC",
    key1   "TEST1",
    key2   "TEST2"
}
```

---

If you don't mind installing another module, you can also use [Ref::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ref::Util) to do this. It's written in XS and is very fast. If you're interested in how that works under the hood, here's a talk SawyerX gave about it [at the German Perl Workshop 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s063VkNrNLU), and again a few month later [at YAPC::NA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gv-DCM9I8v0)<sup>1</sup>.

```
use Ref::Util 'is_arrayref';

foreach my $key (keys %conf_data) {
    $conf_data{$key} = $conf_data{$key}->[-1]
        if is_arrayref($conf_data{$key});
}
```

---

<sup>1) funny enough, he is wearing the same t-shirt in both</sup>

Comment: this solution in fine but my doubt is there any way we can handle it from Config::Genral module

Comment: @Developer that was rather easy to find in the documentation.